# UIButton Under UIview cannot touched

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I add `UIButton` under `UIView` but I add action target it cannot to touched:

this is my code:

```
testview.swift

import UIKit

class testview: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var comment:UIButton!
    }
```

in `viewconrtroller.swift`

```
class ViewController:UIViewController,UIScrollViewDelegate{
@IBOutlet var inner:testview!
@IBOutlet var sc: UIScrollView!
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sc.delegate = self
        sc.isScrollEnabled = true
        sc.delaysContentTouches = false
        sc.contentSize = CGSize(width:320, height:1805)
        inner.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        inner.isExclusiveTouch = true
        inner.comment.isEnabled = true
        inner.comment.addTarget(ViewController(), action: #selector(touched(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}
@IBAction func fullcomment(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("touched")
}
```

Comment: Why you need a button under the view?

Comment: I use scroll view and add uiview under uiscrollview

Comment: You mean to say you have a scrollview and inside that scrollview there is a view and a button which is behind that view in scrollview?

Comment: Yes I mean my Layer is Viewcontroller-->ScrollView-->UIView

Comment: And where is the button?

Comment: I add button via UIStoryboard

Comment: Make sure that the button is on UIView then it will work fine

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
inner.comment.addTarget(ViewController(), action: #selector(touched(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

to

```
inner.comment.addTarget(self, action: #selector(fullcomment(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be of various reasons:
1. UIView frame.
2. UIButton frame.
3. InnerView that is TestView (Is it a customView which is in dedicated XIB or just a custom view).
 and many more depends on your implementation.

You can try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    sc.delegate = self
    sc.isScrollEnabled = true
    sc.delaysContentTouches = false
    sc.contentSize = CGSize(width:320, height:1805)
    inner.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    inner.isExclusiveTouch = true
    inner.comment.isEnabled = true
    inner.comment.addTarget(self, action: #selector(fullcomment), forControlEvents: .touchUpInside)
```

}

```
func fullcomment(sender: UIButton) {
        print("touched")
}
```

Here your selector name was different. I am not sure even if you have another touched method or not.

*Just create IBAction from interfacebuilder.*

*And if the case is 3rd one then you should add target in TestView class itself.*

Comment: Yes you can use this in Swift 3 now

Comment: then this is wrong on your answer  #selector(fullcomment)

Comment: What is wrong? Earlier you can use #selector(functionName(_:)) but now in Swift3 you can use #selector(functionName)..

Comment: I think it's fine. Even we don't give parameter like (_:) then also we get the reference of button in its action. Try that out

Comment: @yasuhiro Did it help?

Comment: I'll check it in 3rd point `override func layoutSubviews() {
       print("view load")
        comment.addTarget(feeddetailViewController(), action: #selector(feeddetailViewController.fullcomment(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }` it true?

Comment: I'll check it in 3rd point `override func layoutSubviews() { print("view load") comment.addTarget(ViewController()), action: #selector(ViewController.fullcomment(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside) }` it true?

Comment: First of all you should not add target in layoutSubviews and second you should action to the button wherever you are dropping its outlet or you can say owner of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126593/discussion-between-krishna-kumar-and-yasuhiro-kondo).

Answer (score 0):

inner.comment.addTarget(self, action: #selector(fullcomment), for: .touchUpInside)

// Action

```
 @IBAction func fullcomment(_ sender: UIButton) 
 {
    print("touched")
 }
```

sc.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

inner.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

inner.comment.isEnabled = true